# binary name for primitive type in ITypeBinding

Tags: java, primitive-types

In `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom`, under ITypeBinding interface, there's `getBinaryName()` and `getName()` method. The explanation under `getName()` is very detailed for each type. However, it's not quite clear in the javadoc. Although I can find detailed explanation of the binary name for each type in java language specification 3rd edition, section 13.1, i can't find the binary name for primitive type.

What's the binary name for primitive type there? and any source that I can check?

Comment: You mean this: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.jdt/core/3.8.1/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ITypeBinding.java That's not standard java...

Comment: @SnakeDoc you are right. It's not in java jdk. Do you know the answer?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the JDT, but think this should be the names defined in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#wp276 (if this is correct, I'll turn this comment into an answer)

Comment: @sunraincyq what is it exactly you are asking? What `getName()` returns when you call it? Are you able to test this on your end (I don't have the eclipse sdk setup otherwise I'd test). `ITypeBinding` is just an interface -- so what it returns would be dependent on the specific implementation you are using/writing.

Answer (score 0):

From `The Java® Language Specification - Java SE 7 Edition`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1

> 13.1. The Form of a Binary
>
> Programs must be compiled either into the class file format specified by The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, or into a representation that can be mapped into that format by a class loader written in the Java programming language.
>
> Furthermore, the resulting class file must have certain properties. A number of these properties are specifically chosen to support source code transformations that preserve binary compatibility. The required properties are:
>
> The class or interface must be named by its binary name, which must meet the following constraints:
>
> - The binary name of a top level type (§7.6) is its canonical name (§6.7).
> - The binary name of a member type (§8.5, §9.5) consists of the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by $, followed by the simple name of the member.
> - The binary name of a local class (§14.3) consists of the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by $, followed by a non-empty sequence of digits, followed by the simple name of the local class.
> - The binary name of an anonymous class (§15.9.5) consists of the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by $, followed by a non-empty sequence of digits.
> - The binary name of a type variable declared by a generic class or interface (§8.1.2, §9.1.2) is the binary name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by $, followed by the simple name of the type variable.
> - The binary name of a type variable declared by a generic method (§8.4.4) is the binary name of the type declaring the method, followed by $, followed by the descriptor of the method as defined in The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, followed by $, followed by the simple name of the type variable.
> - The binary name of a type variable declared by a generic constructor (§8.8.4) is the binary name of the type declaring the constructor, followed by $, followed by the descriptor of the constructor as defined in The Java Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, followed by $, followed by the simple name of the type variable.

~

The `binary name` is the class name of your object. So, for example, the binary name for `Integer` is `Integer`. For `MyCustomClass` is `MyCustomClass`, etc.